# Keeping Docker logs only in memory

Tags: docker, logging

There are various log drivers available for Docker but it looks like all of them persist the logs to disk.

To reduce disk usage I would like to keep the logs only in memory (and limited to a certain size).

I could use log driver `none` but I believe it immediately discards all log messages and sometimes it is still helpful to look at the currently produced logs without having to restart the container to switch to a different log driver.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be, I never tried, is to mount a memory filesystem (tmpfs) and let docker log to that directory with syslog

create a memory filesystem:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18752_01/html/817-5093/fscreate-99040.html

let docker log with syslog:

https://www.simulmedia.com/blog/centralized-docker-logging-with-rsyslog